# How can I differentiate two different touches on a layer?

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

I am writing an app in cocos2d.
I hava a sprite and a text in my scene. I have written two separate classes for sprite and text. And I added both of them to another class.
In sprite class I have written

```
- (void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

And in text class I have written

```
    -(void) registerWithTouchDispatcher
    {

  [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher]addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowsTouches:YES];
    }

    -(BOOL) ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
     return YES;
    }

    -(void) ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
 NSLog(@"Recognized tOuches in Instructions");// 
 CGSize windowSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
 CCNode *node = [self getChildByTag:kTagNode];
 [node setPosition: ccp(text1.contentSize.width/2,text1.contentSize.height/2 - windowSize.height)];

    }

    -(void) ccTouchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

    {
 CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView: [touch view]]; 
 CGPoint prevLocation = [touch previousLocationInView: [touch view]]; 

 touchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: touchLocation];
 prevLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: prevLocation];

 CGPoint diff = ccpSub(touchLocation,prevLocation);

 CCNode *node = [self getChildByTag:kTagNode];
 CGPoint currentPos = [node position];
 [node setPosition: ccpAdd(currentPos, diff)];

    }
```

But, only touches in the text are recognized and touch of sprite is not recognized ?
How can I differentiate the two touches. Can anyone suggest better method for it than my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I did get what I need by using coordinates . I wrote if-else conditions in textclass(the class which touches are recognized in my program). I differentiated the text and the spriteImage by using the coordinates.
Like  this in text class, But do I have any better method. I think this is very crude method.

```
-(void) ccTouchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

{
CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];   
CGPoint prevLocation = [touch previousLocationInView: [touch view]];    

touchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: touchLocation];
prevLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: prevLocation];


if( (touchLocation.x < 300) )
    {
    CGPoint diff = ccpSub(touchLocation,prevLocation);
    CCNode *node = [self getChildByTag:kTagNode];
    CGPoint currentPos = [node position];
    [node setPosition: ccpAdd(currentPos, diff)];
    }
}

-(void) ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
    touchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: touchLocation];

    if( (touchLocation.x < 300) )
    {
        CGSize windowSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
        CCNode *node = [self getChildByTag:kTagNode];
        [node setPosition: ccp(text1.contentSize.width/2,text1.contentSize.height/2 - windowSize.height)];
    }

    else if( (touchLocation.x > (gun.position.x - gun.contentSize.width/2)) && (touchLocation.x < (gun.position.x + gun.contentSize.width/2)) && (touchLocation.y > (gun.position.y - gun.contentSize.height/2)) && (touchLocation.y < (gun.position.y + gun.contentSize.height/2)) )
    {
        CCScene *Scene = [CCScene node];
        CCLayer *Layer = [optionPage node];
        [Scene addChild: Layer];

        [CCDirector sharedDirector] setAnimationInterval:1.0/60];
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pushScene: Scene];
    }
}
```

Thank You.